# Geohash36 for PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

i was wondering if anyone created a ST_GeoHash36 function inside postGIS,

i know the ST_GeoHash + ST_GeomFromGeoHash functions exists,

But i need the geohash36 function inside postGIS, i need a smaller hash:

info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash-36

ruby implementation:
https://github.com/clothesnetwork/geohash36

online demostration:
http://geo36.org/bdrdC26BqH-m

Anyone know if this exists?

Txs!

---

## ** Solution! **

i made a postgresql function that use the geohash36 script!
works great!

geohash36_encode function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geohash36_encode(double precision, double precision)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
echo `/bin/sh /opt/geohash36_coords.sh hash $1 $2`
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION geohash36_encode(double precision, double precision)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

geohash36_decode function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geohash36_decode(character varying)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
LAT=`/bin/sh /opt/geohash36_coords.sh coords $1 | cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 2`;
LON=`/bin/sh /opt/geohash36_coords.sh coords $1 | cut -d':' -f 3 | cut -d' ' -f 2`;
echo $LAT,$LON
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION geohash36_decode(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

example:

[image]

geohash36_coords.sh code:

```
#! /bin/bash
#echo $1 $2 $3

if [ $1 = "coords" ]; then
               echo `geohash36 coords $2`
            fi

if [ $1 = "hash" ]; then
               echo `geohash36 hash $2 $3`
            fi
```

**IMPORTANT:**
YOU NEED TO HAVE THIS ALREADY INSTALLED :
https://github.com/clothesnetwork/geohash36

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  Probably good to put in a feature request.  If its easy enough, it might get implemented in next version of PostGIS (PostGIS 2.2).  We haven't called feature freeze yet.

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found a good solution.  If in the future you don't want to, or can't, rely on an external shell script you can bring your ruby implementation into the database through PL/Ruby.

Comment: thats' great ill try that.

Get external shell inside sql its kind of unsecure.. so pl/ruby its a safer and more compact solution.

I'll try that thanks!!